# How do i download and save data to a folder in my ionic mobile app using angular HTTP Client and capacitor/filesystem?

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, httpclient, capacitor

I am still pretty new to this so I will try to be as clear as possible. I am developing a mobile app using Ionic with Angular. I have a bunch of .mp3 files (and a test.json files which reads "hello world") stored in AWS that I would like the user to have the option of downloading and playing on the app.

I am using the angular HTTP client to get the .json file and display it just using regular old observables, so I know that part works.

I have also been able to use capacitor/filesystem plugin to write, read, and delete data to a specified folder within the app files. https://capacitorjs.com/docs/apis/filesystem
But I am confused when reading the filesystem documentation about how to specify what data to write and where the data should go. (i.e. what is the difference in a path and a directory?)

Here I have used the example code from the documentation to read, write, and delete a simple file like so:

```
    writeSecretFile = async () => {
      await Filesystem.writeFile({
        path: 'secrets/text.txt', // The path of the file to write
        data: 'You found the secret file!', // The data to write
        // directory: // The Directory to store the file in
    });
    };

    readSecretFile = async () => {
      const contents = await Filesystem.readFile({
       path: 'secrets/text.txt', /// The path of the file to read
       // directory: /// The Directory to read the file from
      });
      console.log('secrets:', contents);
      };

      deleteSecretFile = async () => {
        await Filesystem.deleteFile({
        path: 'secrets/text.txt', //The path of the file to delete
        // directory: /// The Directory to delete the file from
       });
      };
```

Essentially, I want to use something like:

```
   let dataToSave = this.http.get(this.ROOT_URL + '/test.json');
```

and pass it to a file system write function but I run into a bunch of errors no matter what I have tried. How should I go about this?